# Obj-C - Programmatically setting NSWindow Appearance to NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark, not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode9, theming

Using XCode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000) I would like to dynamically allow the user to change the theme of a Mac app from Light to Dark etc, but I'm falling at the first hurdle.

I tried putting the following code in both `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and ViewController's `viewDidLoad` methods, but neither caused the theme to change to Dark theme.

```
NSAppearance* appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
    [self.window setAppearance:appearance];
```

I was unable to find an Apple sample showing how to do this programmatically. Can anyone point out what I've overlooked??

Comment: Your code works absolutely perfectly in a brand new, non-document project in Xcode 9.4.1 on macOS 10.13.6 for me, executed in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, linked against the 10.13 SDK. Can you try the same? If it works, something else is going on in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work by moving my code to the controller's `viewWillAppear` (as per sample below). Then everything is themed correctly!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];

    NSAppearance* appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
    [self.view.window setAppearance:appearance];
}
```